# How to use UNPIVOT Convert Column to Row Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, converters, pivot-table

I want query UNPIVOT Cnvert Column to Rows with SQL Server 2008 R2.

But it's Error

```
**Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Line 16: Incorrect syntax near 'unpivot'.**
```

**Code:**

```
SELECT EmpNo, CDate, CTime
FROM
(SELECT EmpNo,ChkDate,ChkIn,ChkOut
  FROM TA_FillTime) ta1
UNPIVOT
(CTime FOR CDate IN (ChkIn, ChkOut)
) AS ta2
```

**Table TA_FillTime:**

```
EmpNo   | ChkDate       | ChkIn                   | ChkOut  
1290005 | 2013-05-09    | 2013-05-09 07:04:26.000 | 2013-05-09 17:57:36.000 
1320005 | 2013-05-09    | 2013-05-09 07:56:17.000 | 2013-05-09 18:24:35.000 
1320007 | 2013-05-09    | 2013-05-09 07:45:50.000 | 2013-05-09 17:24:55.000
```

**I need Output:**

```
EmpNo   | CDate      | CTime    
1290005 | 2013-05-09 | 2013-05-09 07:04:26.000
1290005 | 2013-05-09 | 2013-05-09 17:57:36.000
1320005 | 2013-05-09 | 2013-05-09 07:56:17.000
1320005 | 2013-05-09 | 2013-05-09 18:24:35.000
1320007 | 2013-05-09 | 2013-05-09 07:45:50.000
1320007 | 2013-05-09 | 2013-05-09 17:24:55.000
```

Thanks for you time, :)

Comment: The query which you have written will actually convert `ChkIn` and `Chkout` columns to row value .Check [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6a40/2)

Comment: I hope this helps http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/29/sql-server-unpivot-table-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
EmpNo, ChkDate, CDate = ChkIn
from TA_FillTime
union all
select 
EmpNo, ChkDate, CDate = ChkOut
from TA_FillTime
order by 
EmpNo, ChkDate
```